# Angular jest, test if inside observable

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-observable, angular-unit-test

*Function to be tested*

```js
changeIva(idTax: number, index: number): void {
    this.documentService.getTaxById(idTax).subscribe(tax => {
      if (tax.codigo === 'ISE') this.openModal(index);
    });
  }
```

[image: coverage]

*How far I've come*

```js
it('should test whether the tax is exempt or not', () => {
    const taxMockSuccess = taxMock[0];
    const idTax = 106;
    const index = 1;
    const modalOpenSpy = spyOn(component['modal'], 'open');
    const documentServiceSpy = spyOn(documentService, 'getTaxById').and.returnValue(
      of({ taxMockSuccess })
    );

    component.changeIva(idTax, index);

    expect(documentServiceSpy).toBeCalledWith(idTax);
    expect(modalOpenSpy).toBeCalled();
  });
```

**I need help, I don't know how to test this IF within the subscribe**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `tax.codigo` to `'ISE'`. This will then pass through the IF statement properly.

Change the spy so the returned value handles this

```
    const documentServiceSpy = spyOn(documentService, 'getTaxById').and.returnValue(
      of({ taxMockSuccess })
    );
```

Whatever `taxMockSuccess` is, it should have the value for the `codigo` property set to `'ISE'`.